# How to stop ajax from repeating previous request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have multiple `div` tags with an trash-can icon.
Each `div` refers to a unique name but the trash-can icon functions the same for all `div` tags.
When the trash icon is `clicked` a modal reveals (using foundation.zurb).
The modal is a `form` with two `input` values: `OK` and `Cancel`.

When the `OK` button is `clicked` I want the `form` to `submit` the unique name of the `div` tag that triggered the modal to reveal.  This is what I have:

```
$('a#delete-book').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('clicked delete');
    event.preventDefault();

    var school, book, genre, url;

    var self = $(this);
    school = $("#school-name").text();
    book = self.parent().children('h3').text();
    genre = self.parent().children('span').text();
    url = '/' + school + '/' + book + '-' + genre;
    console.log('url:\n', url);

    //REVEAL MODAL
    $('#deleteModal.reveal-link').trigger('click');

    doesThisWork(self, url);
  });//DELETE END

  function doesThisWork(self, url) {
    console.log(self, url);

    //EVENT LISTENER ON YES
    $('form#delete-book-form').on('click', function(mevent) {
      console.log('delete-book confirmed');
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE",
        dataType: "json"
      })
      .done(function() {
          console.log('delete successful');
          self.parent().remove();
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        console.log('error:\n', err);
        alert('error:\n', err);
      })
    });//DELETE CONFIRM END
  }
```

I can't figure out why when I delete another book the previous ajax request is submitted again.
Am I missing an `event.preventDefault()` somewhere?

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is that you bind events multiple times to the **form#delete-book-form** element (for each click on an **a#delete-book** element):

```
$('form#delete-book-form').on('click', function(mevent)
```

So every time you do this a new handler will be attached to the click-event. You could try to unbind the event on the line before your .on-statement in order to remove previous bind:

$('form#delete-book-form').[off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)('click');